# Using PDO and sessions to create a login form

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I have created a login-logout form using PDO and php session. Here is the entire code for different pages

LOGIN FORM

```
<form role="form" class="omb_loginForm" action="login.php" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        <input  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) 
        {
            try
                {
                    $email      = $_POST['email'];
                    $password   = $_POST['password'];

                    $dbhost     = "localhost";
                    $dbname     = "abc";
                    $dbuser     = "abc";
                    $dbpass     = "pwd";

                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :password ";

                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email'], ':password'=> $_POST['password']));

                    $num=$stmt->rowCount();
                    if($num > 0)
                        {
                            header("location:dashboard.php");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            header("location:login_form.html");
                        }

                }
            catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                }
        }
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "abc";
    $dbuser     = "abc";
    $dbpass     = "pwd";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

    session_start();
    $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email= :$user_check");
    $result->execute(array(":usercheck"=>$user_check));

    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $login_session =$row['email'];
    $user_id =$row['id'];
    $user_passwords = $row['password'];

    if(!isset($login_session))
        {
            $conn = null; 
            header('Location: login_form.html');
        }
?>
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="profile">
        <b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
        <b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) 
    {
        header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
?>
```

the problem that i am facing is that when the i try to login with the correct credentials the form gets redirected to login_form.html whereas it should go to dashboard.php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is `:$user_check`. Sugget you to change like below.

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = :user_check");
                                                             /*^^^*/
$result->execute(array(":usercheck"=>$user_check));
```

Answer (score -2):

I also see another error in there: I see an undefined index at

`$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];`

Where does 'login_user' come from?