# display profile page after login using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592629/using-pdo-and-sessions-to-create-a-login-form/26592660#26592660/) code as a reference to create a login page but when i get redirected to the home page after login i am able to see the dashboard but along with it i am also getting these 2 errors

1) Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

2) Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

These errors are coming due to the session page.

**session.php**

```
<?php
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "abc";
    $dbuser     = "abc";
    $dbpass     = "pwd";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

    session_start();
    $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = :user_check");
    $result->execute(array(":usercheck"=>$user_check));    
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    $login_session =$row['email'];
    $user_id =$row['id'];
    $user_passwords = $row['password'];    
    if(!isset($login_session))
        {
            $conn = null; 
            header('Location: login_form.html');
        }
?>
```

can anyone tell how these errors can be removed?

P.S when i am changing the :$user_check to :user_check OR usercheck in the query (according to it the next array statement also gets changed) the login page stops getting redirected to the dashboard, instead it is getting directed to the login page again.

Comment: Usually supplying your actual code is a great start. Not copy pasting.

Comment: We need to see the real code, I am guessing your first error is a typo.

Comment: error 1 is most likely due to a parameter typo, ie `->prepare("SELECT FROM tbl WHERE username = :userName"); ->execute(array(":username"=>$_POST['username'])` and error 2 is probably cause by error 1 printed to the page before headers are set/sent

Comment: `WHERE email= :$user_check` should be `WHERE email= :user_check` **EDIT** `:user_check` != `":usercheck"`. Change one or the other

Comment: @Sean i tried doing so but when i do so the page is not getting redirected to the dashboard

Comment: If you are using the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592629/using-pdo-and-sessions-to-create-a-login-form/26592660#26592660/ then the issue is most likely that `$_SESSION['login_user']` is never set in `login.php` so `$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];` == `$user_check=NULL;` so your query is basically `"SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = NULL"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected, there is a typo causing the first error.

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email= :$user_check");
$result->execute(array(":usercheck"=>$user_check));
```

should be

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email= :usercheck");
$result->execute(array(":usercheck"=>$user_check));
```

Your second error is probably happening because you have not put `session_start();` at the very top of your script.

Comment: close, but look again -> `:user_check` != `:usercheck`

Comment: Ah, correct and fixed.

Comment: @EternalHour the page in not getting redirected to the dashboard. i have updated the ques plz can u go thru it

Comment: The code you provided is different than the code in your link, your code doesn't redirect to a dashboard.

Comment: @EternalHour sry it was the server problem due to which the code didn't worked, thanks for the help